# how to store request object in session scope in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I was just doing random trick & testing in my `jsp` pages. I wanted to store `request` scope object in `session` scope object using `Attributes`. After storing when tried to extract the value from request attribute (stored in session attribute), I got `null`. Why is it so?
Following are my `jsp` files:

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%request.setAttribute("request1", "requestValue"); %>
<%session.setAttribute("req1", request); %>
<br>
<a href="jsp2.jsp">link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**jsp2.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<%HttpServletRequest rrrr=(HttpServletRequest)session.getAttribute("req1"); %><br>
<%=rrrr.getAttribute("request1")%><br>
</body>
</html>
```

**browser output**

```
null
```

**expected output**

```
requestValue
```

.........................................................

I need your guidance in this problem.

Comment: You shouldn't try to use a request after the request has been handled. A request is not supposed to be usable once it has been handled. Define your own objects, containing the relevant information from the first request, and store those objects in the session.

Comment: sorry, but I am not able to get your point. Can you explain it further?

Comment: Every time you make a request to your server, a new HttpServletRequest is created, and is passed to the servlet and JSPs that generate the response for this request. Once the response has been sent, consider the request object as unusable. Don't store it anywhere to use it later.

Comment: I think i got it, you mean to say that when I am calling `jsp2.jsp`, then a totally new `HttpServletRequest` will be created and that's why I am getting `null`, because previous `request` object has been vanished...is that so?  please clarify if I am wrong.

Comment: It hasn't vanished, since you have stored a reference to it in the session. But you can't rely on this object being functional anymore, because you would use it in a context when it can't be used anymore. You can't expect milk to have good taste and be healthy if you drink it after its expiry date. You can't expect a request to be usable after it is handled.

Comment: haa ha ha..Thanks brother. Your explanation is superb specially that milk part.

Comment: so in order to use request-attribute thing.. it should be there in a same request. just now, when I replace `href` code with `jsp:forward` action, it showed perfect output. Thank You for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with following code:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("req1", request);
```

And when you retrieve the request value you have to do this as:

```
<%= ((HttpServletRequest) rrrr.getAttribute("req1")).getAttribute("request1") %>
```

After all this: If you want to store an Object in session better way is to store it directly into session, instead of storing a request as attribute in session. See below code:

To store attribute:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("obj1", Object); //  Object is any object that you want to store
```

and retrieve it as:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
Object o = session.getAttribute("obj1");
```

Comment: `Http Status 500` exception occurred.

Comment: but, brother, If `Object` is any object, then why not `request` object. Also, how can i store key-value pair in `Object`

Answer (score 1):

Request object shouldn't be stored in the session. As JB Nizet wrote it shouldn't be used out side of current request. Container may decide for example to reuse that object later on, while handling different request, resetting all its attributes.

You can get parameters and attributes from **current** request using methods `request.getParameter()` and `request.getAttribute()` and if you need them for later you can store them in session. You can also store your arbitrary objects in session. For example like this (fragment):

```
String paramForLater = request.getParameter("p1");
// store parameter
session.setAttribute("paramForLater", paramForLater);

// store some data
Person personData = new Person();
session.setAttribute("personData", personData );

// you can retrieve these object later in different jsp like this
Person personData = (Person) session.getAttribute("personData");
String param = (String ) session.getAttribute("paramForLater");
```

Methods request.set/getAttribute() are used only, while handling current request.
For example you may set some parameters in servlet(controller), then access them in the jsp (view) to which that **same** request was forwarded. in pattern like this:

```
// in servlet get your data e.g. from database
MyEntity entity = // code to get entity;
request.setAttribute("entity", entity);
request.getRequestDispatcher("view.jsp").forward(request, response);


// then in jsp you can access that paramter 
<%
MyEntity e = (MyEntity) request.getAttribute("entity");
... // do something in entity
%>
```

You probably should use EL expression instead of scriplets, but this theme for another discussion :).

Comment: Thanks @Gas. Very nice explanation with code. JB Nizet thank you also. Yeah, I would be learning EL for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, when I replaced `href` code with `jsp:forward` action, it showed perfect output.

for each server request a new `HttpServletRequest` object is created. Therefore, when i was navigating to `jsp2.jsp` page using `href`, it created new HttpServletRequest object for `jsp2.jsp`.

Comment: If you use forward, you don't need to store request any where, since the same object is available in your start page and the forwarded one (as it is still same request).