# Increment variable in JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, mysql-workbench

I am working on a flight reservation system where users can log into an account to make reservations.

In my sql database, I have a table called ticket where there is a column called seatnum. I have another table called aircraft and that has a column called seats.

In my jsp page, I want to assign a random seat number to a person buying a ticket, but I can only assign so many seats before the seats in the aircraft table gets full.

I want to declare a global counter for the number of seats I assign to a particular flight, but my counter keeps being reset to 0 but I can't declare a static variable in a jsp. What should I do instead?

```
CREATE TABLE `ticket` (
  `cid` int,
  `flight_num` int,
  `ticket_num` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `seatnum` int, 
PRIMARY KEY (`ticket_num`),
FOREIGN KEY (`flight_num`) REFERENCES flight (`flight_num`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (`cid`) REFERENCES user (`cid`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) 

CREATE TABLE `aircraft` (
    `2letterid` varchar(2),
    `aircraft_num` int,
    `seats` int,
PRIMARY KEY (`2letterid`, `aircraft_num`),
FOREIGN KEY(`2letterid`) REFERENCES `airline` (`2letterid`)
) 

int counter = 0;
String seats = "select seats from flight join aircraft(flight_num) " +
                "where flight_num = " + flightNum;

if (counter > seats) {
enter a waiting list
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the counter in a hidden field or in the session.

Comment: What would that look like?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25459515/how-to-store-request-object-in-session-scope-in-jsp

Comment: If a user logs into an account and makes a flight reservation and then logs out, and another user logs in and makes a flight reservation on the same flight, if I store that in a session, then when the user logs out, the counter variable would be lost also.

Comment: In that case, you can either store it in a cookie or store in in the database for that user.